# Android: Resizing Views Based On Screen Resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a checkers game.  The checkers board is defined as a GridView with 8 columns and 8 rows.  Each red tile is an ImageButton, and each black tile is an ImageView (because red tiles are playable and black tiles are not).  The ImageButtons and ImageViews each have a drawable in them that is either a red checker, a black checker, or no checker.  Each drawable is 50dpx50dp.

I am trying to get the board to resize itself so that it always fills about 80% of the available screen.  The first thing I tried is creating "small", "large", and "xlarge" variants of the drawables, and that gets me pretty close, but the difference between a "small" screen and a "large" screen is pretty substantial, and this results in a lot of wasted screen real estate on devices that fall somewhere in the middle between "small" and "large".

I'd like to programmatically resize the drawable based on a calculation involving the current screen resolution.  I'm happy to implement a screen resolution listener, but I'm not sure how to connect the listener to the drawable images, or if there's a better way to do this.

I did some Googling to see what I can find, and most of the stuff I came across talked about using different pixel densities, but that's not really the problem I have.  I also found a bunch of stuff about using relative layouts and so on, but that doesn't work for a checker board.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions at all as to how to accomplish this.  Thanks!

**EDITED TO ADD**

Based on the comment from @ben-p I have modified my code, and I'm getting closer.  In my layout file, I now have:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And in the fragment layout file, I have:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="8">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Tile00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cc0000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_checkers_red_tile"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/game_checkers_player_none" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_checkers_black_tile"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/game_checkers_player_none" />

    <!-- repeated for a total of 64 tiles -->

</GridLayout>
```

This constrains the checkerboard to a square on the screen with a 1:1 aspect ratio, but it is not scaling the checkerboard to show all 8x8 tiles.  In the example below, you can see that the board is cropped:

[image]

What's the magic incantation to get the ConstraintLayout to scale up/down the contents of the fragment so that it always fits exactly in the space provided?

Comment: I'd suggest using a `ConstraintLayout` to hold your `GridLayout` (so that you can easily make the grid be 80% of the screen) and then using vector drawables for your images so that you can just stretch them to fill each cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  That's gotten me a bit further, but it's not quite there yet.  I've added some code and a screen cap to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the main view code a bit:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then I had to change the fragment layout code as follows:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="8">
    
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Tile00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#cc0000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_checkers_red_tile"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/game_checkers_player_none" />
    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_checkers_black_tile"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/game_checkers_player_none" />

    <!-- repeated for a total of 64 tiles -->

</GridLayout>
```

Once I did that, the checkerboard now scales up to fill the available space.